# How do I get all GET values from a URL? (Missing Values)

Tags: php, get, query-string

I am looping through GET values and only getting 13 values, not matter what URL I submit. Also, it is not getting the values in sequential order...

When I loop through I only get 13 values, as well as when I use a var_dump on $_GET itself; even though there are many more values to retrieve.

Here is the URL:

website.com/Questionaire.php?SurveyName=TV%20Quiz&SurveyType=MultipleChoice&Q1=Choose%20a%20character%20off%20of%20Happy%20Days?&A1=Benny%20the%20bull&A2=The%20Fonz&A3=Jack%20Cracker&Q3=Favorite%20Friends%20character?&A1=Ross&A2=Monica&A4=Joey&A5=Rachel&A6=Chandler&A7=Phoebe&Q8=Favorite%20Nickelodeon%20show?&A1=Hey%20Arnold!&A2=Rugrats&A8=Ahhhh!%20Real%20Montsters

Here are my results:

```
SurveyName: TV Quiz

SurveyType: MultipleChoice

Q1: Choose a character off of Happy Days?

A1: Hey Arnold!

A2: Rugrats

A3: Jack Cracker

Q3: Favorite Friends character?

A4: Joey

A5: Rachel

A6: Chandler

A7: Phoebe

Q8: Favorite Nickelodeon show?

A8: Ahhhh! Real Montsters
```

As you can see the results are not in sequential order and some values are even missing.

```
var_dump($_GET);

foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) { 
    echo $key.": ".$value."<br/>\n";
}
```

I expect these results:

```
SurveyName=TV Quiz

SurveyType=MultipleChoice

Q1=Choose a character off of Happy Days?

A1=Benny the bull //<- missed

A2=The Fonz //<- missed

A3=Jack Cracker

Q3=Favorite Friends character?

A1=Ross //<- missed

A2=Monica //<- missed

A4=Joey

A5=Rachel

A6=Chandler

A7=Phoebe

Q8=Favorite Nickelodeon show?

A1=Hey Arnold!

A2=Rugrats

A8=Ahhhh! Real Montsters
```

Comment: You know that there are multiple A1s in the query string... this is incorrect.

Comment: Why on earth are you trying to pass all of this data via the URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have identical parameter names in your query string, otherwise the last value will overwrite the previous ones. You need to have unique answer names or you will lose data. You can imagine PHP adding the parameters to `$_GET` with the following pseudo-code:

```
foreach($param as $key=>$val) {
    $_GET[$key] = $val;
}
```

Because of this, parameters appear in the order in which they first show up in the request. So the query string `?A=1&B=2&A=3&C=4` will have `A` appear first, then `B`, and finally `C`. The last value for an identical parameter is the one used, so we get the following `$_GET` result:

```
array(
    'A'=>3,
    'B'=>2,
    'C'=>4
);
```

Consider adding the question identifier as a prefix for each answer. For example, instead of `A1` do `Q1A1` and `Q2A1`. This will ensure that your data is not overwritten.

Comment: Holy cow, I cannot believe I didn't catch that sooner, omg... Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: @Christhemist No problem! Sometimes you just need a fresh set of eyes. It's easy to get tunnel vision when you're coding :)

Comment: Note you can have multiple duplicate keys in your query string if you use square brackets as array notation. `?Q1=Question one&Q1A[]=Answer One&Q1A[]Answer Two`

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Just to elaborate on your point to avoid confusion for other readers: by adding the square brackets, the parameter is treated as an array and a new element is added to it. No squares brackets means the parameter is treated as a primitive value and a simple assignment occurs. In short, it's the difference between an array push operation and a variable assignment operation.

Comment: @B.Fleming Thank you for expanding, I feel like you said that much more clearly than I would have.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using array notation for query string parameter names so that order is maintained. Something like:

```
?SurveyName=TV Quiz
&SurveyType=MultipleChoice
&Q[1]=Choose a character off of Happy Days?
&A[1][1]=Benny the bull
&A[1][2]=The Fonz
&A[1][3]=Jack Cracker
&Q[3]=Favorite Friends character?
&A[3][1]=Ross
&A[3][2]=Monica
&A[3][4]=Joey
&A[3][5]=Rachel
&A[3][6]=Chandler
&A[3][7]=Phoebe
&Q[8]=Favorite Nickelodeon show?
&A[8][1]=Hey Arnold!
&A[8][2]=Rugrats
&A[8][8]=Ahhhh! Real Montsters
```

When you name query string parameter like that, PHP will parse them into arrays:

```
array(4) {
  ["SurveyName"]=>
  string(7) "TV Quiz"
  ["SurveyType"]=>
  string(14) "MultipleChoice"
  ["Q"]=>
  array(3) {
    [1]=>
    string(37) "Choose a character off of Happy Days?"
    [3]=>
    string(27) "Favorite Friends character?"
    [8]=>
    string(26) "Favorite Nickelodeon show?"
  }
  ["A"]=>
  array(3) {
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
      [1]=>
      string(14) "Benny the bull"
      [2]=>
      string(8) "The Fonz"
      [3]=>
      string(12) "Jack Cracker"
    }
    [3]=>
    array(6) {
      [1]=>
      string(4) "Ross"
      [2]=>
      string(6) "Monica"
      [4]=>
      string(4) "Joey"
      [5]=>
      string(6) "Rachel"
      [6]=>
      string(8) "Chandler"
      [7]=>
      string(6) "Phoebe"
    }
    [8]=>
    array(3) {
      [1]=>
      string(11) "Hey Arnold!"
      [2]=>
      string(7) "Rugrats"
      [8]=>
      string(21) "Ahhhh! Real Montsters"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Christhemist Although my answer is the one to point out the cause of your problem, consider using the approach noted here for your actual code. An ordered array approach is much easier to handle by far.